# Angular 4 project and TFS

Tags: angular, tfs

Currently we have a VS solution with a sub folder that holds all front-end files. The whole folder is included into solution. Any time anything has been checked in a TFS build generates distribution packages where front-end files are simply copied into. With Angular 4 I want to use AOT compiling to reduce a size of packages, perform error validation, and etc. I have searched online for some references about how to integrate Angular 4 build process with TFS CI but didn't find much. Can someone please point to good tutorials?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS build process template, you need add the [npm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/npm) task to install the Angular CLI and dependencies.

Check the articles below:

- https://sethreid.co.nz/deploying-angular-cli-project-using-vsts-build-release/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/05/17/integrating-angular-4-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/

Comment: Both articles are for integrating Angular and VSTS. We are using a TFS build server to create distribution packages. Is it still applicable for me?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? VSTS and TFS have similar build steps.

Comment: About Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 15.105.25910.0

© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: It's TFS 2017 RTM version. You could use the same steps as VSTS. By the way, you can upgrade your TFS to latest edition Update 3 first.